# SDWAN Control Plane Bandwidth limiting

Tags: cisco, networking, sd-wan

I have an Cisco SDWAN network and my edge devices MUST not exceed a specific bandwidth/rate for the given transport.  I can create policing/QoS polices for the data-plane.  As for the control-plane, does policing/QoS policies also need to be created or is that an automatic feature of SDWAN?  That is, control-plane traffic is always given highest priority?

Answer (score 1):

Control plane traffic is the management and critical traffic of the device(s). It should not be rate limited *on* the control plane as it needs to be processed and dispatched as quickly as possible.

The data plane is where inbound and outbound traffic is first 'seen' and as such, any traffic that might end up going to the control plane can be classified or rate limited there.

As a metaphor, where do speed limits and express lanes do the most good? On highways and large roads or in a driveway and parking garage of your home?

The driveway and parking garage would be conceptually similar to the control plane, because they are used for the 'internal management' of your vehicle and its maintenance, etc. The data plane is the bulk of the roadways where your vehicle and others do the majority of their actual travel and spend their most functional time so the controls are most important and effective there.

That said, there are 'control plane policing' features on many devices that are either automatic or can be adjusted manually. You haven't mentioned any specific models so it is impossible to say whether your devices have those features but many do. Features such as automatic rate limiting for new connection attempts to specific protocols for management, etc. These help to protect the load of the control software features of the device.